# Parse tag in html via Google Sheets (importxml)

Tags: html, parsing, google-sheets

in this website :
https://www.tankathon.com/mock_draft

I want to retrieve the tag href="**/players/zaccharie-risacher**">

From this

```
<div class="mock-row-player">
   <a class="primary-hover" href="/players/zaccharie-risacher">
      <div class="mock-row-name">Zaccharie Risacher</div>
      <div class="mock-row-school-position">SF | JL Bourg </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

I’ve tried

```
//a[@href/contains("players")]
```

with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tankathon.com/mock_draft","//a[contains(@href,'players')]")
```

In this modification, `//a[@href/contains("players")]` is modified to `//a[contains(@href,'players')]`.

#### Testing:

When this formula is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

### Added:

From your following reply,

> I’m not looking for : Zaccharie Risacher // SF | JL Bourg, but really looking for the tag "/players/zaccharie-risacher", is it possible?

About `the tag "/players/zaccharie-risacher"`, the following formula is your expected one?

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tankathon.com/mock_draft","//a[contains(@href,'players')]/@href")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I’m not looking for : **Zaccharie Risacher  // SF | JL Bourg**, but really looking for the tag **"/players/zaccharie-risacher"**, is it possible?

Comment: @mika_972 Thank you for replying. About `the tag "/players/zaccharie-risacher"`, by guessing your expected result, I added one more sample formula, please confirm it. If that was not your expected result, I apologize again.